# gui git client for auto-complete

Tags: macos, git, git-tower

in `trotoise svn`
if I have many changed files in one commit,

for examples, I committed these three files

```
config/application.yml
db/schema.rb
app/views/streaming_verifications/index.html.haml
```

those file name can be auto-completed on the tortoise message window,

Is there any equivalent auto-complete function to acheive this on OSX ?

or if it is an bad way to log commit message ?

I'm using `gittower` now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have an autocompletion feature in Tower for this.

### I wouldn't directly call it a "bad way", but I can say that not many users mention concrete filenames in their commit messages. Often, the message is used to describe the changes on a higher / more abstract level.

Tower Support
support[at]git-tower.com